# regular expression find & replace: first capital letter conditional

Tags: regex, monodevelop

So I have my regex find and replace partially working in MonoDevelop. Here's the problem:

I have a bunch of instances of

lights
numberOfLights
lastNumberOfLights, etc

and I want to change all of them to

vantagePoints
numberOfVantagePoints
lastNumberOfVantagePoints, etc

Right now I am using:

FIND:    ([Ll])ights

REPLACE: $1oots

And it works, it turns lights into loots and Lights into Loots. But how can I use a different capital letter? lights into boots and Lights into Boots

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the way is to use 2 regular expression instead of one, e.g.

```
FIND: Lights
REPLACE: Boots

FIND: lights
REPLACE: boots
```

Comment: It isn't a regular expression. It is just a double search with two words